# Flutter Listview why is the title not changing?

Tags: flutter, listview, dynamic

so I've got a question:
My question is a bit complicated but I try to explain it to you...
So my App works like that when I tap on the image the image changes and the title too (like Porridge)
You are able to tap on the title and you come to the second Page but there the title doesn't change that is my problem because I am using the List
[image: app][image: problem]

Here it is chnaging (first Screenshot):

```
class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DicePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  int PicNumber = 1;

  void changeDiceNumber() {
    setState(() {
      PicNumber = Random().nextInt(4) +1;
    });
  }



  final List<Sachen> infoBank = [
    Sachen(title: "Schoko-Bowl", image: Image.asset("Images/frue1.png"), text: '-Mehl'),
    Sachen(title: "Smoothie-Bowl", image: Image.asset("images/frue2.png"), text: '-Zucker'),
    Sachen(title: "Porridge", image: Image.asset("images/frue3.png"), text: '-Milch'),
    Sachen(title: "Porridge", image: Image.asset("images/frue4.png"), text: '-Eier'),
    Sachen(title: "Schoko Mousse", image: Image.asset("images/frue5.png"),text: '-Butter'),

  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 35, 50, 0),
            elevation: 15,
            color: const Color(0xFF4caf50),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 80,
              width: 180,
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 18),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Rezept('Dein Frühstück'),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(infoBank[PicNumber].title,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                            ),
                      ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      PicNumber++;
                    });
                    changeDiceNumber();
                    print('LeftDiceNumber = $PicNumber');
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 415,
                    width: 350,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 3,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: FittedBox(
                        child: infoBank[PicNumber].image,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here it's not changing it is the code for the second Screenshot:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Sachen.dart';
import 'dart:math';


class Rezept extends StatelessWidget{
  final String rezept;
  Rezept(this.rezept);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF4caf50),
        title: Text(rezept),
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
      ),
      body: RezeptPage(),
    );
  }
}

class RezeptPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RezeptPage ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RezeptPageState createState() => _RezeptPageState();
}

class _RezeptPageState extends State<RezeptPage> {
  int PiNumber = 1;

  void changeDiceNumber() {
    setState(() {
      PiNumber = Random().nextInt(4) +1;
    });
  }



  final List<Sachen> infoBank = [
  Sachen(title: "Schoko-Bowl", image: Image.asset("Images/frue1.png"), text: '-Mehl'),
  Sachen(title: "Smoothie-Bowl", image: Image.asset("images/frue2.png"), text: '-Zucker'),
  Sachen(title: "Porridge", image: Image.asset("images/frue3.png"), text: '-Milch'),
  Sachen(title: "Porridge", image: Image.asset("images/frue4.png"), text: '-Eier'),
  Sachen(title: "Schoko Mousse", image: Image.asset("images/frue5.png"),text: '-Butter'),

];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 15),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 8,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Center(
                    child: Text(infoBank[PiNumber].title,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 350,
          height: 500,
          child: Card(
            elevation: 5,
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 20),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 10, 0),
              child: RichText(text: const TextSpan(
                  text: 'Zutaten:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                      decorationThickness: 2.0,
                    ),
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                          text: '\n\n-Mehl' '\n-Zucker' '\n-Milch' '\n-Eier' '\n-Butter',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: '\n\nZubereitung:',
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: '\n\n-Zuerst vermischen wir alles' '\n-Anschließend wird es in der Pfanne angebraten' '\n-Zuletzt mit Schokolade bestreichen und genießen',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
              ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    ],
    );
}
}
```

I hope you understand my question and already thank you

Comment: Can you include your 1st screen widget?

Comment: you mean the code of the first page where the image and title is?

Comment: yap, the page where title comes from and where it is not changing

Comment: I added the code to my question

Comment: Cant find any appBar here, can you include `Rezept`

Comment: Rezept is the second code not everything but the important part but I will at everything

Comment: Sorry i am missing something. it doesnt reproduce the same issue. For 1st page there is not appBar. You can check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question really is, how to pass a value, in your case PiNumber, from one screen to the other. That is what you need to do when pushing to the other screen. Here is an article that explains how this works: https://fluttercorner.com/how-to-pass-value-from-one-screen-to-another-screen-using-navigator-in-flutter/